# how to write a text editor in c++

Tags: c++

I learned c++ on and off for several times but never write a real apps using it .
long time I've been thinking that writing a text editor will be something very interesting , now I am looking for a simple but decent text editor written in c or c++ from which I can get inspiration and learn how to write a text editor by myself.

Could you guys recommend a "simple but decent" text editor written in c or c++ to me ?

Comment: Despite my conviction that we're done this before, I haven't found an exact match---it is a hard one to search. Here are some related resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845527/how-fast-does-it-take-to-write-a-simple-custom-editor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047537/text-editor and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179299/how-do-shell-text-editors-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well what you want to see sounds more like a tutorial than an actual application (I think applications like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/de/site.htm) will be a lot to dive into in the beginning). Since you don't mention any environment you want to program in, you could check out the [QT Text Editor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html) Demo. QT is a cross platform GUI Toolkit so you are not bound to a specific operating system but probably harder to setup then a Visual Studio environment in Windows.

For Windows only you might want to think about digging more into the .NET platform (e.g. C#) as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433162/vc-win32-or-wpf-for-developing-a-text-editor). It doesn't help learning C++ but it makes GUI development a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: Just adding on to this answer, I have been working on a text editor project for the past two years, feel free to take a look at it for inspiration: https://github.com/Hexman768/Notepad-Sharp

Answer (score 20):

You might want to look at [Zile](http://www.gnu.org/software/zile/) or [nvi](http://www.bostic.com/vi/).  Both are fairly simple; Zile is Emacs-like, and nvi is the Berkeley `vi`.  Another to look at would be [Nano](http://www.nano-editor.org/), a simple text editor that is designed to be easy for new users.  I don't know how clean the code is on any of these, though.

I would also recommend reading [The Craft of Text Editing: Emacs for the Modern World](http://www.finseth.com/craft/).  This book surveys many of the specific problems that have to be dealt with in writing a text editor along with approaches, strategies, and algorithms for solving them.  Its content should be relevant and useful even if your editor isn't going to look much like Emacs at all.

Comment: Is there any similar resource like 'The Craft of Text Editing', which specifically deals with handling text data,for editing, specially multiple buffers of huge files (in GB's) with efficient memory usage? It seems before diving into source code, it would be helpful to have a good theoretical base.

Answer (score 4):

Get the vi.
There is a big lack of true editors like vi/vim ;)
I mean there is a plenty of editors like notepad/notepad++,
but few editors which have separate command/control mode.
So You could look at the vi sources to inspire yourself and introduce something revolutionary.

Comment: There's reasons why there's few editors with separate command/control mode.  Don't get me wrong, I live in vim, but the separate modes don't add much to it (compare Emacs, for example), and are hard to learn.

Comment: There are plenty, but they activate 'control mode' while you hold 'Control' button.

Comment: I agree with You, but I'm sick of getting another clone of notepad ;) .
I want something really new.
That was my message.

Answer (score 4):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) is an excellent open source editor written in C++.

Answer (score 2):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/about.php) for some definitions of "simple".

Comment: Simple? Are you sure? It may be a very nice text-editor but it's filled with tons of useless features (search wikipedia, as if anyone will use that).

Answer (score 2):

You may also check out [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) editing component.

Answer (score 1):

[JuffEd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/juffed/). It is written in C++, cross platform due to usage of Qt and QScintilla. Notepad++ uses also Scintilla text editor component, but its limited only to Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

What sort of text editor would you like to make?

First question is will this be GUI or Console based?

GUI based, do you want to make something like Notepad? And on what platform? If it's MS Windows based, might I recommend picking up on MFC?

If it's text based, there are many open source solutions you can get into. My recommendation is to look at the simplest of editors like ed or something.

Answer (score 0):

loot to the QT this is cross platform,HAVE RICHTEXT COMPONENT(widget).Writing first app in QT will give you actual knowledge.I recommend to learn QT by book